# Bluetooth Arduino and Serial monitor not working

Tags: android, arduino

Im trying to make an app on my android phone and I want to control my arduino using the serial monitor, basically, if I press a button on my app, it will send an "A"or a "B" to my serial monitor, and that should do something, but I was trying to test my code using only the serial monitor, and when I write "A" it doesn't show anything and don't even do anything, is there a problem between the bluetooth module (HC-06) and the serial monitor of my pc? or maybe is a problem of coding? by the way, my bluetooth module is connected to Tx/Rx on my ArduinoUNO board

```
const int BTPWR = 11;
byte led = 9;
char nombreBT[10] = "SafeSleep";
char velocidad = '4'; //9600
char pin[5]= "0000"; 
byte sensor = 8;
const int SPWR = 7;
char valor;
int t;
int ta;
int count;

 void setup(){ 
   pinMode(SPWR,OUTPUT);
   pinMode(sensor,INPUT);
   pinMode(led,OUTPUT);
   pinMode(BTPWR,OUTPUT);
   digitalWrite(led,LOW);
   digitalWrite(BTPWR,HIGH);

  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.print("AT");
  delay(1000);

  Serial.print("AT+NAME");
  Serial.print(nombreBT);
  delay(1000);

  Serial.print("AT+BAUD");
  Serial.print(velocidad); 
  delay(1000);

  Serial.print("AT+PIN");
  Serial.print(pin);
  delay(1000);

  digitalWrite(led,HIGH);
}


void loop(){
  t = 60000;
  if (Serial.available()){
    valor = Serial.read();

  if (valor == 'A'){
    Serial.print("Sensor encendido");
    digitalWrite(SPWR,HIGH);
    count = 0;
    if(digitalRead(sensor)==HIGH){
    count = count + 1;
    Serial.print("Se detecto movimiento");
    ta = millis();
    if(ta - t >= 0 ){
       t = 0;
     if (count >= 20){
      count = 0; 
      Serial.print("Bebé con posible trastorno del sueño");
     }


  }

 }
 if(digitalRead(sensor)==LOW){
  Serial.println("No hay movimiento");

  }

  }
  if (valor == 'B'){
  digitalWrite(SPWR,LOW);
  }

}
}
```

PD: I don't have problems in connecting my module to the cellphone, but the app doesn't work at all, so I was trying to make sure my code was fine

Answer (score 0):

The Arduino hardware has built-in support for serial communication on pins 0 and 1.
When using your Arduno with a module for communications like the HC-06 module, the best way to implement its communication would be using the `SoftwareSerial` library, as it has been developed to allow serial communication on other digital pins of the Arduino, using software to replicate the functionality.

I don't see any point of your code where you are making this connection at all. To use the SoftwareSerial library with your HC-06 it is as easy as doing something along these lines:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial hc06(2,3);

void setup(){
  //Initialize Serial Monitor
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("ENTER AT Commands:");
  //Initialize Bluetooth Serial Port
  hc06.begin(9600);
}

void loop(){
  //Write data from HC06 to Serial Monitor
  if (hc06.available()){
    Serial.write(hc06.read());
  }
  
  //Write from Serial Monitor to HC06
  if (Serial.available()){
    hc06.write(Serial.read());
  }  
}
```

Notice how in this sketch we are initializing two serial monitors, the native one from the Arduino, and the serial communication with the HC-06.